# Programmatically create NSButton and set custom NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

Ok, this seems like it should very simple, but I'm coming from iOS and and I must be missing something very obvious. So I have a custom subclass of NSButtonCell. If I create a NSButton in IB and assign the NSButtonCell in IB, it works no problem.

However, I need to programmatically create this button. I've looked at a couple of examples and have the following within awakeFromNib, however, it creates what appears to be a regular button with my custom button cell underneath (I can tell when I click on the button).

```
NSButton* button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 60, 30)];
CT_CaptureButtonCell* captureCell = [[CT_CaptureButtonCell alloc] init];
[button setCell:captureCell];
[captureCell release];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

So what dumb thing am I missing / not understanding? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't understood what you're trying to do.The button appears regularly and when you click on in you can see the button cell.What did you except to see instead?

Comment: For testing purposes, the custom button cell is red. I see a regular button, but when I press the regular button shifts slightly and I can see the red cell around the edges. I'm expecting to see the red button all the time (which is what I see when I hook things up in IB).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation for "`setCell:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setCell%3a), it states:

> **Discussion**
>
> Use this method with great care as it can irrevocably
>   damage the affected control; specifically, you should only use this
>   method in initializers for subclasses of NSControl.

The way I read this is that you should be calling your "`setCell`" from *within* the init method for a subclass of "`NSButton`".  In other words, write your own NSButton subclass (e.g. "`ICButton`", for InfalibleCoinage) and then stuff the "`setCell`" call into the init method there.

And while we're on the subject, what's the big picture of what you are exactly trying to accomplish with "`CT_CaptureButtonCell`" and can you do it without using a custom button cell?

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I subclasses NSButton and modified as follows. However, it gives me the same behavior. I did try creating a nib with just the custom button and that works, but seems an awkward way to do it. (And I'm using a custom button cell to have state dependent custom drawing/graphics)
[code](- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code here.
        [self setCell:[[[CT_CaptureButtonCell alloc] init] autorelease]];
    }
    
    return self;
})

How do you format code in a comment ??!!??